# How to get the deselected value from mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table, inside the table i have this mat-select:

```
<mat-select multiple placeholder="{{element.name}}" [(value)]="selectedCol" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)" [disabled]="!selection.isSelected(element.id)">
          <div *ngFor="let item of col">
            <div *ngIf="item.Id === element.id">
              <mat-option [value]="item.id"> 
                {{item.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </div>
          </div>
</mat-select>
```

I need to get the value that was deselected, so i can remove it from the list of selected values, because every row in my table is saved in one variable on "selectionChange".

Comment: Can you not perform this actions through your  (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)" ?

Comment: I can't, (selectionChange) only returns the selected values, but i need the one that i deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed the deselected value because I have more mat-selects with the same ngModel/value. To solve it i used the [SelectionModel Class](https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular_components/angular_components/SelectionModel-class).

Answer (score 0):

On Html side

```
(selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
```

on ts Side

```
selectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
      console.log(event.value)
}
```

where value is list of objects (array)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the value that was deselected, so i can remove it from
>   the list of selected values, because every row in my table is saved in
>   one variable on "selectionChange".

**Why??** Angular make the work for you. Use [(ngModel)] or a FormControl

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
{{toppings|json}}

//in your .ts
toppings:any[]=[]
```

or

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [(formControl)]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
{{toppings.value|json}}
//in your .ts
  toppings = new FormControl();
```